# Al llamar a un método desde JavaScript a c# con HtmlControl me pide que sea estático?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, visual-studio

Mediante **Ajax** intento llamar a un método en C#.

El método en C# me debe insertar un código HTML según el control ID, pero me pide que sea estatico.

**Codigo HTML:**

```
<div class='card-text text-dark'><strong>Nombre</strong></div>
<div id ='PolizaDatosPersonalesNombre' class='card-text' runat='server'></div>
<br />
<div class='card-text text-dark'><strong>Apellidos</strong></div>
<div><span id ='PolizaDatosPersonalesApellido1' class='card-text' runat='server'></span>&nbsp;<span id ='PolizaDatosPersonalesApellido2' class='card-text' runat='server'></span></div>
<br />
```

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'MisPolizas.aspx/VerPolizaDetalle',
     data: "{poliza: '" + idPoliza + "'}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
          success: function (msg) {
              alert('OK');
     },
          error: function (e) {
              alert('KO');
     }
```

**Metodo C#:**

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void VerPolizaDetalle(string poliza)
    {
       Poliza currentPoliza;
       currentPoliza = polizas.Where(x => x.PolizaID == poliza).Distinct().ToList()[0];



       PolizaDatosPersonalesNombre.InnerHtml = currentPoliza.DatosPersonales.Nombre;
       PolizaDatosPersonalesApellido1.InnerHtml = currentPoliza.DatosPersonales.Apellido1;

     }
```

En `PolizaDatosPersonalesNombre` y `PolizaDatosPersonalesApellido1` me pide que sea estatica.

Lo he intentado también quitando el [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] y el static del metodo VerPolizaDetalle(string poliza) quedando como: public void VerPolizaDetalle(string poliza) .En este caso me llega a compilar el proyecto pero al hacer la llamada con Ajax me devuelve el mensaje de alert 'KO'

Comment: Por favor, indica el código completo AJAX, y la descripción del error que te da.

Comment: Creo que no es problema de Ajax aun asi pondre el codigo. El mensaje de visual studio antes de compilar es que me pide que PolizaDatosPersonalesNombre y PolizaDatosPersonalesApellido1 sean declaradas como estaticas. Pero estas ya vienen declaradas con el runat='server' como instancias de elemento HtmlControl

Comment: Por que no lo regresas en un JsonResult y con js le asiganas los valores ya que mediante ajax lo estas tratando de hacer

Comment: Esto ocurre porque el método ```VerPolizaDetalle``` que estás llamando es estático. Un miembro estático no puede tener acceso a un miembro no estático.

Comment: Si asi es, pero si VerPolizaDetalle no lo declaro como estatico no puede usarlo con Ajax

Comment: @EdgarVazquez no entiendo lo que me comentas

Comment: Algo como esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/24412574

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente lo que estás intentando hacer es **imposible**.

Al tener definido tu método `VerPolizaDetalle(string poliza)` como `[WebMethod]` (**Servicio Web**), no es posible que puedas acceder a los objetos de tu página, ya que estos **no existen** a la hora de establecer la llamada (*Postback*).

Supón que tu servicio web (WebMethod) es llamado desde cualquier otra página web que no sea la que tuya, sería imposible de identificar los controles `PolizaDatosPersonalesNombre` y `PolizaDatosPersonalesApellido1`(son controles `runat=server` de tu página aspx).

Además, los WebMethods son **estáticos** por definición, y tu estás intentando referenciar en su interior a objetos no estáticos de la página aspx. Por eso te da ese error.

Una alternativa es que mediante AJAX, envíes los datos al método y los recibas como parámetros.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void VerPolizaDetalle(string poliza, string PolizaDatosPersonalesNombre, string PolizaDatosPersonalesApellido1)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: y como recibiría Ajax los parámetros? Lo que me interesaba es que desde el propio código c# y con runat='server' cambiar esos parametros

Comment: @Popularfan Lee por favor detenidamente mi respuesta. Y como te solicité anteriormente, indica el código completo AJAX donde realizas la llamada al WebMethod.

Comment: acabo de agregar el código Ajax tal como lo tengo. También he quitado el static del método C# y el [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] para que me compile el proyecto pero al llamar con Ajax me devuelve el alert con 'KO'